# Lucene prohibit subclass Query from parsed Query

Tags: java, lucene

Is there any built in mechanism to prohibit/filter out queries that should not contain specific query types? For example if I prepare a query consisting of `TermQuery`/`WildcardQuery`/`PointRangeQuery`/`RegexpQuery`. Is there a simple way to filter out `RegexpQuery` from our prepared Query? Or atleast detect `RegexpQuery` and reject the whole Query? Or do I have to detect this on my own?

I.e.:

```
Query a;
if (a instanceof RegexpQuery) {
    return; //reject
}
```